# PHP script to find files of certain extensions in a directory, returns populated array when run in browser, but empty array when run from terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, cron, file-permissions

I am running OS Ububtu 16.04. My ultimate goal is to be able to run a PHP script as a cron job every minute. Here is the PHP script located at `/var/www/html/Tests/Test/index.php`:

```
<?php

$directoryPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Tests/Test/data/";
echo "directoryPath: $directoryPath<br><br>";//check

$imageFilePathsArray = glob($directoryPath . "*.{png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

echo "<br><br>imageFilePathsArray: "; print_r($imageFilePathsArray);//check

?>
```

When I open this PHP script in the *browser* by visiting the URL `MY-IP-ADDRESS/Tests/Test/index.php`, I get:

```
directoryPath: /var/www/html/Tests/Test/data/

imageFilePathsArray:Array( [0] => /var/www/html/Tests/Test/data/pic.png [1] => /var/www/html/Tests/Test/data/pic.gif )
```

Before writing the cron job in my cronTab file, I need to check if I can run this from anywhere using the *terminal*. So I opened up the Ubuntu terminal at the `/home/` location, and executed in terminal:

```
sudo php /var/www/html/Tests/Test/index.php
```

I got the following output:

```
directoryPath: /var/www/html/Tests/Test/data/

imageFilePathsArray: Array (
)
```

**The question is that why do I get an empty array when the same script is run from command line, whereas a fully populated array when it run from the browser?**

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (just like most `$_SERVER`-params) is populated by the web server. When you're running your script from the terminal, the web server is never involved and thus, that value isn't set.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you so very much. If you can write that as an answer, I can mark it as the accepted answer. That will also help future visitors.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` when you're running your script through CLI.

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (just like most `$_SERVER`-params) is populated by the web server. When you're running your script through CLI, the web server is never involved and thus, that parameter won't be set.